# Translating user stories in UML diagrams

Tags: uml, object-oriented-analysis, user-stories

*Could I translate user stories in UML diagrams to teach oriented object project? *Is it right? 
*Is there someone with experience in it?

Comment: Do you mean _teach_  or _learn_?

Comment: This really isn't a programming question, but a meta-programming question about how to learn to program.

Comment: I mean to teach. I am teaching OO analysis and design in an undergraduate course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is an interesting one, and using use case to model story is a debate and I am quite sure that there are a lot's of talk about UML usage in Scrum or Agile method.

I am not sure that Scrum experts would agree that a user story is a use case. For example, for me a use case is associated to a full description and for my understanding this is not the case of a user story.
Maybe this [difference between use case and user story](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/235039/what-is-the-difference-between-use-case-user-requirements-and-user-stories) could help.

Answer (score 2):

UML has "Use Case Diagrams" which are pretty much the UML version of a User Story.